# Hibernate on a different server as the webserver

Tags: database, hibernate, webserver

I understand Hibernate enough to develop around it. But I wonder if I can get hibernate to sit on a different box all-together, and direct all traffic a IP and port of that box.

That way I can upgrade hibernate the way I want, and manage it the way I want, without having to worry about the webserver production environment.

**Edit :**
I need the whole working of the hibernate to be on a different box. We are thinking of optimizing the hibernate layer for performance and would rather have our own "server" to play, upgrade around with.

Comment: Hibernate is just an API. It doesn't do anything by itself. You need code that uses its API. So no, Hibernate can't sit on a different box. You could have a server, running code using Hibernate, and you could call this server from your webserver. Not sure what you would gain, except headaches and a performance drop.

Comment: Do you want something like only business logic (which are linked with database) in a different machine?

Comment: Nope, I need the whole working of the hibernate to be on a different box. We are thinking of optimizing the hibernate layer for performance and would rather have our own "server" to play, upgrade around with.

Comment: Replacing direct in-memory accesses by network calls to another server won't improve performance. It will dramatically decrease it. What's the problem in "playing" with the web server? How is it different than playing with a non-web-server?

Comment: Deployment and Sales story gets more interesting if we have a box to sell :). Imagine walking up to a production based environment and convincing them to update parts of their webserver's.

Comment: I imagine, yes. How would that be different than convincing them to update their business logic server? A web server is a server, which happens to accept HTTP requests. You can deploy an app based on Hibernate on a server which doesn't accept HTTP requests if you want. But you'll need a way to communicate with this server somehow. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I see your point. Also agree with the in-memory/network calls. Obviously thinking is not right. thanks